# Python print format with dot leader

Tags: python-3.x, printing, printf, string-formatting

How can I use print format to place a set of characters (dot leading) between 2 objects?

For example, I have the following code:

```
os.chdir( "LOGS\\" )
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'HOST_POWER="ON"' in contents:
        print('{0:38} {1:3}'.format(file[:-4]," = ON"))

for file in glob.glob('*'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'HOST_POWER="OFF"' in contents:
        print('{0:38} {1:3}'.format(file[:-4]," = OFF"))
```

Output:

```
server1.web.com          = ON
server2.web.com          = ON
server3334.web.com       = OFF
server5332223.web.com    = ON
server2233.web.com       = ON
server44.web.com         = ON
server1133333.web.com    = OFF
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
server1.web.com ............ ON
server2.web.com ............ ON
server3334.web.com ......... OFF
server5332223.web.com ...... ON
server2233.web.com ......... ON
server44.web.com ........... ON
server1133333.web.com ...... OFF
```

server{SPACE}............{SPACE}ON

server{SPACE}............{SPACE}OFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just edit the string before you pass it to print (edited to get exactly the kind of formatting you want):

```
import glob

def padStr( x, n ):
    x += ' '
    return x + '.'*(n - len(x) )

for file in glob.glob('*.*'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'HOST_POWER="OFF"' in contents:
        print('%s %s' % ( padStr(file[:-4], 38 ),"ON"))

for file in glob.glob('*'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'HOST_POWER="OFF"' in contents:
        print('%s %s' % ( padStr(file[:-4], 38 ),"OFF"))
```

> Output:

```
blahblahblah ......................... ON
f1 ................................... ON
tes .................................. OFF
```

Comment: I found I was able to achieve the same results using:  print(( padStr(file[:-4], 40 ) + " ON"))

Comment: `'%s %s' % (a,b)` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'.format( a, b )`. Sorry, I should have used that. I prefer the other notation and used it out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Another (slightly messier) option is to fix the string in line before using it as a format arg:

```
print('{0} {1:3}'.format((f[:-4]+' ').ljust(38, '.'),"= ON"))
```